# Изменить цвет экрана при открытии BottomSheetScafold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheet

Как при открытии BottomSheetScafold затемнить все содержимое в основном экране, то есть в экране под BottomSheetScafold??

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про BottomSheetScafold, но в лоб просится очевидное решение - в основном экране делается Box + content + Box/Spacer/чтоугодно и при открытии BottomSheetScafold менять фон у элемента покрытия.